# Warning is thrown while dynamically dropping a temporary table in SAP HANA

Tags: c#, hana

I am able to drop the temporary table dynamically by using

```
EXEC 'DROP TABLE '||:schemaname||'.'||:tablename;
```

where schemaname and tablename are obtained as input in the procedure.

Problem: I am getting a warning stating

```
Not recommended feature: DDL statement is used in Dynamic SQL (current dynamic_sql_ddl_error_level = 1)
```

Due to this warning, I'm getting exception in C# when I use this procedure.

Isn't DROP supported in dynamic SQL? Help me to handle this either from SAP HANA or at least skip this warning from being caught as an exception in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is supported, but you get a warning nevertheless as it's considered problematic to use DDL in dynamic SQL. 
Basically, you want to avoid doing schema changes in your SQL Script. 
For temp tables there's not really a need to drop them anyway.

The memory can easily be freed up via TRUNCATE TABLE if that's a concern.

Your C# program on the other hand should learn to handle and differentiate errors and warnings. The message you got here is a warning and does not mean an error.

If that's not possible for you to do, then you can still use the sledge-hammer approach to problems: switch off the warning by setting the indexserver parameter
sqlscript - dynamic_sql_ddl_error_level = 0

That's of course **not** recommended, as you may miss out other warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lars Br. I can't use TRUNCATE because I am having a create temp table statement in the procedure. IF EXISTS is not available in SAP HANA. So I had used exception handling previously. Now I'm trying other possibilities to check and drop the temp table if it already exists.  So, I'm calling a table_exists_check procedure with table name as the parameter and inside that procedure, I'm dropping the table dynamically using the EXEC command. So here I want DROP only and NOT TRUNCATE. Is there any other ways to drop a temp table other than EXEC command?

Comment: Well, you could consider to remove the create temp table and simply define a global temp table instead. That saves you the recreation of the table everytime you run the procedure. The data in it will be gone after your session finishes. Alternatively you could use a session local temp table - this one disappears automatically after the session is over.